# Why doesn't this Regex work in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want a regex that will verify that a string begins with a letter followed by some letters, numbers, or underscores.  According to my EditPadPro regex parser the following test should pass.  But it does not.

```
Regex.IsMatch("Class1_1", @"^\w[\w|\d|_]*$").ShouldBeTrue();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Nevermind everyone.  I had a mistype but I did not know that \w includes digits and underscores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex works, but doesn't do what you think it does.

You should use

```
Regex.IsMatch("Class1_1", @"^[A-Za-z]\w*$")
```

(Tested)

Comment: Alternately, "^\w[\w\d_]*$", but, as has been pointed out by David M, \w includes \d and _ anyway, so actually "^[a-zA-Z]\w+$"

Answer (score 3):

\w includes \d and underscore - even if your test passes, the Regex won't be testing what you want it to!

Comment: Regex.IsMatch("Class1_1", @"^\w+$") doesn't work.  Any comment on why?

Comment: Possibly your globalization settings - that expression matches on my machine.